# .Net Model binding a dataset via JSON post

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, angularjs, modelbinder

I am having a heck of a time with this one.  I must be missing something.

I am posting a complex model via Angular/JSON to a .NET controller.  When posting it back to the server the DefaultModelBinder only partially binds to the model (the simple values such as int (ID) and string (title) are fine).  The "ListItems" dataset seems to be ignored as well as the "ProductsList" datatable which are part of the ProjectDetails model.  From what I am reading, for complex objects the DefaultModelBinder takes a second pass at the JSON recursively and then maps the objects that it can find.  I have tried a number of solutions that I found through searching StackOverflow but to no avail.  I think I have just lost my perspective at this point.  Here is what I have.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**The Model**

```
    Public Class ProjectDetails

    Private _ListItems As DataSet
    <JsonProperty("ListItems")> _
    Public Property ListItems() As DataSet
        Get
            Return _ListItems
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataSet)
            _ListItems = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ProductsList As DataTable
    Public Property ProductsList As DataTable
        Get
            Return _ProductsList
        End Get
        Set(value As DataTable)
            _ProductsList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _imageID As Int32 = 0
    Public Property imageID() As Int32
        Get
            Return _imageID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int32)
            _imageID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Title As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Title = value
        End Set
    End Property
    End Class
```

**The Action Controller**

```
    <Authorize()> _
    <AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
    <ValidateInput(False)> _
    Async Function ProjectUpdate(ByVal d As ProjectDetails) As Task(Of JsonResult)
    'send results to database here
    Save(d)
    return json(true)
    End Function
```

**Header**

```
    POST http://localhost:51110/projectUpdate HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:51110
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 10119
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**JSON data posted**

```
    {"ListItems":

    {"ProjectStatusCodes":[{"id":1,"ProjectStatusTx":"Stage1 - Under Construction"},{"id":3,"ProjectStatusTx":"Stage3 - Project Released"},{"id":4,"ProjectStatusTx":"Project Closed"}],

    "ProductsList":[
    {"id":2336,"Name":"Product1","Description":"This is a description","$$hashKey":"00K"},
    {"id":2337,"Name":"Product2","Description":"This is a second description","$$hashKey":"00M"}],

    "imageID":345,
    "Title":"books", }
    }
```

**AngularJS code**

```
    $scope.update = function (formData) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/projectbuilder/projectUpdate',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.formData)
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.codeStatus = status;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.codeStatus = status || "Request failed";

    });
```

**HTML template with form values**

```
    <div ng-repeat="ProductsList in formData.ListItems.ProductsList">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
               <input value="{{ProductsList.Title}}" name="ProductsList.Title" ID="ProductsList.Title" ng-model="ProductsList.Title" >
               <br />
               <input value="{{ProductsList.ImageID}}" name="ProductsList.ImageID" ID="ProductsList.ImageID" ng-model="ProductsList.ImageID" >
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**Behavior**
The JSON post works fine to the controller and it binds the ImageID and Title.  The ListItems dataset contains no tables and the ProductsList datatable in the ListItems dataset does not exist.

NOTE: The ProjectStatusCodes data in the JSON is not mapped back to the model as it was used only for display purposes on the form.

Comment: Are the complex objects bound to a control within the form that you are posting is my first question?  Second have you read this article and tried using Lists<>?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554971/mvc-form-model-returning-null-for-complex-object-collection

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the comment. It is an MVC project so there are no bound controllers or aspx webforms. I added the Angular HTML template with the form fields for clarification.  I read the article about the list approach. What would you suggest for a rewrite of the model?

Comment: Yes, I know this is mvc.  In your view within your form you have to have your model properties bound to something within your form in order for the data itself to "stick around" during the form post.  For your model rewrite instead of using dataset and datatable, I would create an actual class.  So, it would be something like property List<LstItem> and property List<LstProduct>.......... Then on the server side you will have a class for LstItem with its properties and a class for LstProduct.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  As I mentioned earlier I feel like I have lost perspective on this so please bear with me:)   The JSON that I posted is what is successfully getting to the server via the JSON post.  Subsequently it is bound to the form via AngularJS 2-way binding.  If it is being posted it is bound to the form which is what is great about Angular.   The issue seems to be with the DefaultModelBinder.  What is confusing me is that I do already have a class which is used to populate the form and Angular scope and on postback that class structure is maintained.   (cont)

Comment: The DefaultModelBinder is catching everything except the ListItems dataset and ProductsList datatable even though it is clearly being posted back via JSON.  The DefaultModelBinder is supposed to be able to recursively recognize and bind them according the MSDN.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx  It seems like the last part of the puzzle lies in the modelbinder and how it handles datatables/datasets. (cont)

Comment: A custom ModelBinder would be preferable to changing the class as the class is used in a lot of other places in the app and changing it from a datatable to another structure would be problematic.  If we need to we certainly will but do you have any experience with custom binders or are you seeing anything with the JSON formatting that would cause the DefaultModelBinder to choke?   Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, those are just the normal questions I ask when people say they are having trouble getting their data to the server with mvc.  Personally, I have never seen a Dataset or Datatable be bound back to a model from and MVC Json Post.  I know that the more complex the object the more difficult this bind to model can be.  I do know you can create your own modelBinder but that is difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out.  It seems as if JSON.NET does a great job of serializing the object when sending making sure that it is fully JSON compliant.   The bad news is that it removes most of the things that make a datatable de-serializable when sending it back to the .NET application.

What I ended up doing was catching the JSON string on postback and accessing the serialized datatable data separately using the JSON.NET fragment serialization which you can find here. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm  I left the rest of the object "as is" and grabbed the datatable from the JSON string and did a de-serialization manually with this technique.   The example in the article was very informative.

CODE TO READ THE JSON STRING

```
    Dim req As Stream = Request.InputStream
    req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Dim jsonstring As String = New StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd()
```

CODE TO PARSE IT OUT AND DESERIALIZE

```
    Dim ProductsList As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonstring)
    Dim results As IList(Of JToken) = ProductsList("ListItems")("ProductsList").Children().ToList()

    Console.Write(results)
```

Not terribly elegant but it works.

Comment: Some more great info here on decreasing the size of serialized data tables with JSON  http://mvitorino.com/2011/05/28/json-net-custom-datatable-serializerconverter/

Answer (score 0):

If it's trying to serialize "ListItems" from your json into a list object, it might cause issues because you don't have brackets in your json, even if it is only one object in the list:

```
  {"ListItems":[ 
         {
             "ProjectStatusCodes":[{"id":1,"ProjectStatusTx":"Stage1 - Under Construction"},{"id":3,"ProjectStatusTx":"Stage3 - Project Released"},{"id":4,"ProjectStatusTx":"Project Closed"}],
             "ProductsList":[{"id":2336,"Name":"Product1","Description":"This is a description","$$hashKey":"00K"},{"id":2337,"Name":"Product2","Description":"This is a second description","$$hashKey":"00M"}],
             "imageID":345,
             "Title":"books"
         } 
  ]}
```